# Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Int?'

Tags: swift, swift4

I am getting a error after converting Objective-C to Swift. Thanks

```
var gymdays = GymHours.orderedDays()
for i in 0..<gymdays?.count {

}
```

[image: error screen]

My Objective-C code:

```
NSArray *days = [GymHours orderedDays];
for (uint i = 0; i < days.count; i++) {

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Int? is optional, so Xcode is telling you you are trying to use a value that may or may not be there.

You can use the following to avoid a crash if the value is nil:

```
for i in 0..<(gymdays?.count ?? 0) {

}
```

Comment: i am getting this error Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Int?'

Comment: @Siva Sorry, forgot to place ( ) around it to help the compiler infer type. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

You can safely use `if let` to avoid crashes that may result in force unwrapping it if it's nil

```
if let gymdays = GymHours.orderedDays()  {
{
     for i in 0..<gymdays.count { }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Stop trying to convert Objective C code by just writing the closest looking thing in Swift. It (generally) doesn't work, and even when it does, it produces crap Swift code. Instead, learn ObjC and Swift to the point where you can understand what's being expressed in the Objective C code, so you can write the best Swift code to express it.

This code is code is looping over the indices of the `NSArray`. In Swift, you shouldn't use `count` for that. You can just loop over the ... [`indices`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2854166-indices)... of the array:

```
for index in gymDays.indices { ...
```

There is a very high liklihood that on the next line of the Objective C code, you'll see something like `let gymDay = [gymDays objectAtIndex: i]`. In that case, in Swift, you can just iterate over the elements of the array, directly:

```
for gymDay in gymDays { ...
```

If you need both the index AND the element, then you would just use [`enumerated()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated):

```
for (index, gymDay) in gymDays.enumerated() { ...
```